# Is it possible to arrange a html for print?

Tags: css, html

In my html, there are header, sidebar, footer, and `<main>`. They are convenient when reading on browser, but when reader print the page, I want them to print only the `<main>` part because sidebar... etc are not necessary when printed on papers.

Can i select the visible parts when printed?

Comment: Yes, use `@media print` in your css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I have used to print only the desired content.

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    #printable { display: none; }

    @media print
    {
        #non-printable { display: none; }
        #printable { display: block; }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="non-printable">
        Side Bar Content
    </div>

    <div id="printable">
        Main Content
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

sure, you use a media query.

using a media query in your css

```
@media print {
   … css goes here
}
```

You could also use a seperate print.css file

here is an [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) that goes into greater details

Answer (score 0):

Try window.print for printing:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>
```

Then use css to style the items for printing:

```
@media print
{
    header{
      display: none;
    }
}
```